# How to decode some strange JSON data in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, decode

My JSON file is like this:

```
> {
       "skill_list": [
        {
            "Skill": 78
        },
        {
            "Skill": 57
        },
        "None"
    ]
},
{
       "skill_list": [
        {
            "Skill": 12
        },
        "None",
        "None"
    ]
},
```

I don't know how to define a struct to this JSON data, and I don't want to
use SwiftyJSON package.

Is there a way to define a struct to decode this JSON data?

Just like

```
JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: data)
```

the whole JSON is like:

```
{
"armor": {
  "param": [
    {
      "skill_list": [
         {
          "Skill": 56
        },
        {
          "Skill": 4
        },
        "None",
        "None",
        "None"
      ]
    },
    {
      "skill_list": [
        {
          "Skill": 103
        },
        "None",
        "None",
        "None",
        "None"
      ]
    }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Looks like Your skill list has always 3 optional skill properties.

Comment: yes it has 3 skill properties, but some is "Skill: value", some is "None", i don't know how to handle it

Comment: But you can't separate on skill_list object from another? I assume your json also contains a pair of [] to make it a valid json?

Comment: I edit my question and i paste the json, it's a valid json from a json file.

Comment: The heterogenous array cannot be decoded synthesized. You have to implement `init(from decoder` and decode the array as `UnkeyedContainer`

Comment: it's too hard for me, would you please give me a demo for this? thank you!

Comment: As it seems that you need to get only the skill_list just declare this as an array of skill. If you do not , put anything for None , json will discard it.

Comment: i try but failed, it shows "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got this, the code is :

```
 let myJson = """
        {
        "armor": {
          "param": [
            {
              "skill_list": [
                {
                  "Skill": 56
                },
                "None",
                "None",
                "None",
                "None"
              ]
            },
            {
              "skill_list": [
                {
                  "Skill": 103
                },
                "None",
                "None",
                "None",
                "None"
              ]
            }
            ]
        }
        }
        """

        struct Armor: Decodable {
            var armor: ArmorClass
        }

        struct ArmorClass: Decodable {
            var param: [ArmorInfo]
        }
        struct ArmorInfo: Decodable {
            var skill_list: [MetadataType]
        }

        enum MetadataType: Codable {
          case Skill(SkillType)
          case string(String)

          init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            do {
                self = try .Skill(container.decode(SkillType.self))
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
              do {
                self = try .string(container.decode(String.self))
              } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(MetadataType.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Encoded payload not of an expected type"))
              }
            }
          }

        }
        struct SkillType: Codable {
            var Skill: Int
        }
        
        let jsonData = myJson.data(using: .utf8)!
        let decodeData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Armor.self, from: jsonData)
        
        if case let MetadataType.Skill(value) = decodeData.armor.param[0].skill_list[0] {
            print(value.Skill)
        }
        if case let MetadataType.string(value) = decodeData.armor.param[0].skill_list[1] {
            print("String: \(value)")
        }
```